# View doesn't reload inside foreach

Tags: swift, swiftui, ios13

I'm using a foreach statement with a @observedObject which contains a published object. I add a appear function to call API, and after update my published var.

Here is my view :

```
struct SurveyListView: View {
    @ObservedObject var VM:SurveyListViewModel
    @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode: Binding<PresentationMode>

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader{ geo in
            ZStack{
                //MARK: - LIST OF OCCURRENCES -
                ScrollView{
                    VStack(spacing:0){
                        ForEach(self.VM.sections){ sec in
                            HomeSectionSurveyView(section: sec.section)
                            ForEach(sec.occurrences){ occs in
                                NavigationLink(destination:SurveyListView(VM: Container.sharedContainer.resolve(SurveyListViewModel.self)!)){
                                    RawSurveyView(occurrence: occs)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }.padding(.bottom,20)
                    .padding(.top,40)
                }
                .padding(.top,geo.size.height * 0.24)
                .onAppear(){
                    self.VM.appear()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and here is my observable object :

```
class SurveyListViewModel: ObservableObject {
    // MARK: - IOC -
    let OccurrenceManager:OccurrenceManager
    // MARK: - INIT -
    init(occurrenceManager:OccurrenceManager) {
        self.OccurrenceManager = occurrenceManager
    }

    // MARK: - APPEAR
    func appear()
    {
        Async.background {
            self.OccurrenceManager.getAllOccurrences ()
        }.main{ occs in
            self.sections = occs.groupByDate()
        }
    }

    @Published var sections:[OccurrenceSection] = []

}
```

I thought that the published var ask the view to reload when it's updated, but nothing changes in my foreach. am I doing something wrong ? thanks

Comment: I think the reason could be the implementation of you OccurrenceSection type. Can you share it? Also it seems to be that you should use List and ForEach instead of ScrollView, VStack and ForEach.

Comment: What happens if you add `objectWillChange.send()` in `SurveyListViewModel.appear()`, just before assigning to `self.sections`?

Comment: I think it should work without that if you add or remove new items to an array (which happens here.) You should use `objectWillChange.send()` if for example an item's property is changing in the array. This might be the case for you because you are storing the sections.

Comment: Stange behavior, this view is the second one in a navigationView, if I back to the first one and back to SurveyListView again my view is updated ... I don't know why it doesn't work at the first push. And objectWillChange doesn't improve my appear function